# How do you compare 2 lists and return the difference? (difference function in python does not return what I need)

Tags: python, list, compare

I am trying to find the difference between 2 lists. Basically, I want to know everything that is in list 1 that is not in list 2. The best way to explain it, is with an example:

```
List1 = [a, a, b, c, d, e]
List2 = [a, b, c, d]

In this example, I would like a function that would return [a, e]
```

When I use the difference function in python, it will only return "e" and not that there is an additional "a" that is in list 1. When I simply used XOR between the 2 lists, it also only returned "e."

Comment: Order doesn't matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is really not set subtraction. You can use a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> List1 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> List2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> import collections
>>> counter = collections.Counter(List1)
>>> counter.subtract(List2)
>>> list(counter.elements())
['a', 'e']
```

Comment: <grumbles>  Well, at least I can add this much: `Counter(List1)-Counter(List2)` works too.  We're lucky here because the OP only wants members of 1 not in 2 (otherwise subtraction would lose an 'f' in 2).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - what cases would ``.subtract`` be different than ``Counter-Counter``?

Comment: @jterrace -- `subtract` doesn't need to be given an instance of `Counter`.  It's mostly a matter of how the code is read:  `Counter(List1).subtract(List2)` vs `Counter(List1) - Counter(List2)`.  There might be some (small) performance gains in the first case, but the second case is maybe slightly nicer to read?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm a new programmer, so I keep getting this error when I try to use this code: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Counter' - Do you know what I may be doing wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: jterrace: yeah, it's only style.  Nothing major, you just beat me. :^)  @user1618063: ah, then you must be working with an old version of Python, pre-2.7.  If possible you should upgrade; there are lots of nice features in 2.7 that people will use in their SO answers.  [Upgrading to 3.2 is still a bit of an issue because not all libraries support it yet, but that's gradually becoming less of a problem.]

Comment: @DSM: Ah yes, that must be it. I'm currently using Python 2.6. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @user1618063 yep, Counter is new in 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `List1` is a strict superset of `List2`:

```
for i in List2:
    if i in List1:
        List1.remove(i)
# List1 is now ["a", "e"]
```

(You can clone `List1` if you don't want to do it in-place.)

Comment: This seems like a place for `try/except`.  No sense looking the item up in List1 twice.